# error MSB6006: "java" exited with code 1 Proguard Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-proguard

I tried to enable proguard to my Xamarin android project. When I run the application in the release mode, I am getting below error.

```
Target _CompileToDalvikWithDx:
/usr/bin/java -jar /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/proguard/lib/proguard.jar -include '/Users/vinoch/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx//tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt' -include 'obj/Release/proguard/proguard_xamarin.cfg' -include 'obj/Release/proguard/proguard_project_references.cfg' -include 'obj/Release/proguard/proguard_project_primary.cfg' -include 'proguard.cfg' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.1.0.3.1/build/MonoAndroid80/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.27.0.2.1/build/MonoAndroid81/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.27.0.2.1/build/MonoAndroid81/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.27.0.2.1/build/MonoAndroid81/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.27.0.2.1/build/MonoAndroid81/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.27.0.2.1/build/MonoAndroid81/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include '/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS - Mobile/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.27.0.2.1/build/MonoAndroid81/../../proguard/proguard.txt' -include 'obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/dc663e480.txt' -injars "'obj/Release/android/bin/classes/../classes.zip'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v8.1/mono.android.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/android-support-multidex.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/14/jl/formsviewgroup.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/16/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/18/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/19/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/22/jl/notification-hubs-0.4.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/32/jl/__reference__pass-v1.2.0.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/32/jl/__reference__sdk-v1.0.0.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/47/jl/bin/SfAutoComplete.Android.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/51/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/52/jl/arch-core-common.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/53/jl/arch-lifecycle-common.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/54/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/55/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/57/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/58/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/59/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/60/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/61/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/62/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/63/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/64/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/65/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/66/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/67/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/68/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/69/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/70/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/71/jl/bin/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/72/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/73/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/74/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/82/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/83/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/84/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF):'obj/Release/lp/85/jl/classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)" -libraryjars '/Users/vinoch/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-27/android.jar' -outjars obj/Release/proguard/__proguard_output__.jar -optimizations !code/allocation/variable 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at proguard.FileWordReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(Unknown Source)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(Unknown Source)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2464,3): error MSB6006: "java" exited with code 1.
Done building target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" in project "EmployeeApp.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I have searched on the internet and have taken below actions,

1. Set Java Heap Size to 1G
2. Updated the JDK to version 1.8+
3. Updated the proguard to version 6.0+

Still the same issue persists. Please note that I have enabled the Multi-Dex as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You have a file in your `.csproj` flagged as a proguard file that does not exist: `/Users/vinoch/Projects/JESS/JESS`

Comment: have you added progaurd.jar to your solution ?

Comment: I have solved this issue by selecting 'Link sdk assembliens only' from 'Link all sdk and user assemblies'.

Comment: Any updates on this. I am currently having this problem?

Comment: any updates? @Hue, did you manage to fix this?